# Writing a switch differently

Tags: java, android, performance, google-maps, optimization

So I have a switch with two cases and what is inside is like 90% similar so my question is, how can I write it differently and save some code, I am pretty much stuck on this, the switch works but I am sure there is another way, more optimal.

I'll explain in depth.

I have the following switch case with two cases.

```
switch (tipretea) {
    case "red":

        break;

    case "green":

        break;
}
```

tipretea is a column from a local database and "red","green" are the values of that column.
Inside the case, I am calling a method that puts markers onto the map, red markers for the "red" case and green markers for the "green" case.

The method looks like below:

```
markeradd(id, bmp, pozastring, adresa, denumire, tipretea, latitude + "", longitude + "", latlng, BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
```

Only the last parameter is changed.

```
BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)
```

for green.

```
BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)
```

for red.

The code is pretty big if you ask me so I am asking you for a better way to write this down, below is the full switch code.

```
switch (tipretea) {
case "red":
    markeradd(id, bmp, pozastring, adresa, denumire, tipretea, latitude + "", longitude + "", latlng, BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
    break;
case "green":
    markeradd(id, bmp, pozastring, adresa, denumire, tipretea, latitude + "", longitude + "", latlng, BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
    break;
}
```

Comment: store the result from the case in a local value like myHue= BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED; and myHue= BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN; Then just call your markeradd method with that result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`float` value](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory.html#HUE_GREEN) for it, change that value in the `switch` and use that `float` in `markeradd` later:

```
float hue = 0;
switch (tipretea) {
    case "red":
        hue = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED;
        break;
    case "green":
        hue = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN;
        break;
}
markeradd(
    id,
    bmp,
    pozastring,
    adresa,
    denumire,
    tipretea,
    latitude + "",
    longitude + "",
    latlng,
    BitmapDescriptorFactory
    .defaultMarker(hue));
```

It is good practice to include a `default` in the `switch` statement for when value that is `switch`ed upon is unexpectedly something else than the provided cases:

```
switch (tipretea) {
    case "red":
        hue = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED;
        break;
    case "green":
        hue = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN;
        break;
    default:
        //TODO Do something to catch the possibility of an unexpected value for tipretea (notify the user / send an error report, something like that).
}
```

Also note that a `break;` statement is not necessary in the last case, because the `switch` will be done then anyhow. Although [something is to be said for always providing the `break;` statement](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/201786).

Comment: It's not equivalent as the original does nothing for a non-matching input (usually no big deal).

Comment: @maaartinus You are right, but like you say, in this case I think this is what the asker wanted to know.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much what I was looking for, thank you @MarchingHome.